# How to check email generated by WHMCS billing system before they are actually sent

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smtp

The WHMCS billing system that I use sometimes generates wrong invoices (due to bug or me using it wrongly due to the complexity of the system) and this is being sent out via SMTP (for my case gmail) to the customer causing much embarrassment.

I'm trying to find a way to "vet" or check before they are actually sent to my customer.  I know what I want to do sounds a bit silly so I'm open to a better approach or alternative method if there is one.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question however a long delay of not paying (I believe a week) will cause WHMCS to add a 25% "late fee" automatically. If you do decide to go this route, make sure you are prompt to check them so people can be notified.

Comment: @chipperyman573 Thank you for your comment. I've disabled the late fee so it's not an issue. That being said, even though I'm using WHMCS, my problem can apply to any automated billing system that emails bills automatically.